# Multidimensional cumulative sum in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to be able to calculate the cumulative sum of a large n-dimensional numpy array. The value of each element in the final array should be the sum of all elements which have indices greater than or equal to the current element.

2D: xᶦʲ = ∑xᵐⁿ ∀ m ≥ i and n ≥ j

3D: xᶦʲᵏ = ∑xᵐⁿᵒ ∀ m ≥ i and n ≥ j and o ≥ k

Examples in 2D:

```
1 1 0       2  1  0
1 1 1  ->   5  3  1
1 1 1       8  5  2

1 2 3       6  5  3
4 5 6  ->  21 16  9
7 8 9      45 33 18
```

Example in 3D:

```
1 1 1       3   2   1
1 1 1       6   4   2
1 1 1       9   6   3

1 1 1       6   4   2
1 1 1  ->  12   8   4
1 1 1      18  12   6

1 1 1       9   6   3
1 1 1      18  12   6
1 1 1      27  18   9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flip along the last axis, cumsum along the same, flip it back and finally cumsum along the second last axis onwards until the first axis -

```
def multidim_cumsum(a):
    out = a[...,::-1].cumsum(-1)[...,::-1]
    for i in range(2,a.ndim+1):
        np.cumsum(out, axis=-i, out=out)
    return out
```

Sample 2D case run -

```
In [107]: a
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [108]: multidim_cumsum(a)
Out[108]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [5, 3, 1],
       [8, 5, 2]])
```

Sample 3D case run -

```
In [110]: a
Out[110]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])

In [111]: multidim_cumsum(a)
Out[111]: 
array([[[ 3,  2,  1],
        [ 6,  4,  2],
        [ 9,  6,  3]],

       [[ 6,  4,  2],
        [12,  8,  4],
        [18, 12,  6]],

       [[ 9,  6,  3],
        [18, 12,  6],
        [27, 18,  9]]])
```

Comment: Of course, thanks! For completeness the solution for my use case in 4D is: `a[...,::-1].cumsum(-1)[...,::-1].cumsum(-2).cumsum(-3).cumsum(-4)`

Comment: @user2685230 Edited with a generic solution based on the same idea.

Comment: This is flipping amazing, and should really be called a rubik's cube :D

Answer (score 5):

For those who want a "`numpy`-like" cumsum where the top-left corner is smallest:

```
def multidim_cumsum(a):
    out = a.cumsum(-1)
    for i in range(2,a.ndim+1):
        np.cumsum(out, axis=-i, out=out)
    return out
```

Modified from @Divakar (thanks to him!)

Comment: Perfect, invaluable!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution. I'm going by the description, not the examples, i.e. order of vertical display is top down not bottom up:

```
import itertools as it
import functools as ft

ft.reduce(np.cumsum, it.chain((a[a.ndim*(np.s_[::-1],)],), range(a.ndim)))[a.ndim*(np.s_[::-1],)]
```

Or in-place:

```
for i in range(a.ndim):
    b = a.swapaxes(0, i)[::-1]
    b.cumsum(axis=0, out=b)
```

Comment: Seems your in-place version has a bug? b is overwritten on subsequent iterations.

Comment: @shaunc _"[...] bug? bis overwritten [...]"_ ??? Isn't that the meaning of _in-place_?

Comment: I mean -- suppose a.ndim > 1. On each iteration, b doesn't depend on the previously calculated value of b, but it gets a new copy from a, ignoring the previous work.