# Is there a reverse operation to scipy.linalg.block_diag?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know scipy offers a handy function to convert from a list of arrays to a block diagonal matrix, e.g.

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import block_diag
>>> A = [[1, 0],
         [0, 1]]
>>> B = [[3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8]]
>>> C = [[7]]
>>> D = block_diag(A, B, C)
>>> D
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

Is there a reverse operation to this? I.e. take a block diagonal matrix and a list of chunk sizes and decompose to a list of arrays.

```
a, b, c = foo(D, block_sizes=[(2,2), (2,3), (1,1)])
```

If there's no handy built-in way to accomplish this, is there a better (more performant) implementation than looping over the input array? The naive implementation probably looks something like this:

```
def foo(matrix, block_sizes):
    result = []
    curr_row, curr_col = 0, 0 
    for nrows, ncols in block_sizes:
        result.append(matrix[curr_row:curr_row + nrows, curr_col:curr_col + ncols])
        curr_row += nrows
        curr_col += ncols
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code for `block_diag`:

The core part allocates a `out` array, and then iteratively assigns the blocks to it:

```
out = np.zeros(np.sum(shapes, axis=0), dtype=out_dtype)
r, c = 0, 0
for i, (rr, cc) in enumerate(shapes):
    out[r:r + rr, c:c + cc] = arrs[i]
    r += rr
    c += cc
```

Were you imagining something more "performant"?

What you want is a list of arrays that (may) differ in shape.  How are you going to get those without some sort of (python level) iteration?

Look at the code for `np.split` (and variants).  It too iterates, taking multiplie slices to produce a list of arrays.

Comment: Appreciate you pointing out the source code! Should have taken a look at that as well. By "more performant" I was curious if there was a clever solution to create jagged arrays using np.reshape or something like that, that may be able to do some vectorization.

Comment: "vectorization" in `numpy` means doing things with the compiled numpy methods (and functions).  Those methods (nearly) always produce numpy arrays (or scalars), not lists of python objects (including arrays).  Keep in mind that jagged/ragged arrays are object dtype arrays, and much like lists, containing references to objects else where in memory.  Operations on such arrays take place a list-comprehension speeds.  The fast stuff works with numbers, `c` ints and floats, not python pointers.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's some code that uses NumPy to get the non-zero block indices, i.e. the corresponding indices where blocks created by `block_diag` would be placed.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def multidim_cumsum_tlbr(a):
    # thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463366
    out = a.cumsum(-1)
    for i in range(2, a.ndim+1):
        np.cumsum(out, axis=-i, out=out)
    return out

def get_block_indices(m):
    """Given a 2D square NumPy array `m` of length `n`, calculates the non-zero
    block indices, such that each block contains some non-zero value. All-zero
    blocks will yield multiple 1-size blocks.

    :param m: a 2D NumPy array
    :return: an array of size `[2, n]`, the first row specifying block start
        indices, the second row being the end indices (non-inclusive).

    >>> get_block_indices(np.array([
    >>>     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,],
    >>>     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
    >>> ]))
    array([[ 0,  1,  3,  4,  5],
           [ 1,  3,  4,  5, 10]], dtype=int64)
    """
    s = np.shape(m)
    if len(s) != 2 or s[0] != s[1]:
        raise ValueError('Only accepts 2D NumPy square arrays')
    
    # Indicate non-zero values.
    x = (m != 0).astype(int)

    # Transpose makes sure that when we count non-zero values for the block,
    # we do so for symmetric matrix.
    x += x.T

    # Count non-zero values along each axis.
    x = np.fliplr(multidim_cumsum_tlbr(np.fliplr(x)))
    x = np.triu(x)

    # Indicate where cumsum is zero.
    x = x > 0

    # Flag elements where all subsequent elements, in both
    # axes, are zero. These are the block ends.
    x = ~x[1:,:-1] & ~x[:-1,1:]

    # Find block indices.
    x = np.nonzero(np.diag(x, 0))[0]

    # Calculate end indices and add the final block as a block index.
    x = np.hstack([x + 1, [len(m)]])

    # Calculate start indices and return the pairs.
    x = np.vstack([np.hstack([[0], x[:-1]]), x])
    return x


blocks = [
    [
        [1,0,],
        [1,1,],
    ],
    [
        [0,0,1,],
        [0,0,0,],
        [0,0,0,],
    ],
    [
        [0,],
    ],
    [
        [0,],
    ],
    [
        [0,0,0,],
        [0,0,0,],
        [1,0,0,],
    ],
    [
        [0,1,],
        [0,0,],
    ],
    [
        [-1,1,0,],
        [0,-1,1,],
        [1,-1,0,],
    ]
]
m = block_diag(*blocks)
x = get_block_indices(m)
for i, (s, e) in enumerate(x.T):
    assert np.all(m[s:e, s:e] == np.array(blocks[i])), (m[s:e, s:e], np.array(blocks[i]))
```

I won't be surprised if there's a nicer way to write this! I would love for people to improve on my answer. Perhaps also dealing with all-zero blocks.